# Write sql statement using linq

Tags: mysql, linq

How can I write the following sql code in LINQ

```
select count(1) Cnt,state 
from yourtable
group by state
order by Cnt desc Limit 5
```

I am trying somthing like this

```
(from topPro in CS.state group topPro by new {
       Name = topPro.state.Name
} into g
select new{
     StateName = g.Key.Name,
     Count = g.Count(x=>x.state)
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a SQL-LINQ conversion tool. Show what you have tried.

Comment: How far have you got so far? Do you have LINQ working with your database at all? Is it using EF? What have you tried for your query? What went wrong? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: @user2998990: use `Count = g.Count()` instead of `Count = g.Count(x=>x.state)`

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer

```
var top5Pros = (from topPro in CS.state
group topPro by new { Name = topPro.state.Name } into g
select new
{
StateName = g.Key.Name,
Count = g.Count()
}).OrderByDescending(w => w.Count).Take(5);
```